# How to sum for previous n number of days for a number of dates in MySQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a list of dates each with a value in MYSQL.

[image: List of values]

For each date I want to sum the value for this date and the previous 4 days.

I also want to sum the values for the start of that month to the present date. So for example:

- For 07/02/2021 sum all values from 07/02/2021 to 01/02/2021
- For 06/02/2021 sum all values from 06/02/2021 to 01/02/2021
- For 31/01/2021 sum all values from 31/01/2021 to 01/01/2021

The output should look like:

[image: Final Output]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What version of MySql? And, please use text, not images, to show sample data ad code.

Answer (score 0):

In MYSQL 8.0 you get to use analytic/windowed functions.

```
SELECT
  *,
  SUM(value) OVER (
        ORDER BY date
    ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEEDING
             AND CURRENT ROW
  )                                AS five_day_period,
  SUM(value) OVER (
    PARTITION BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-01')
        ORDER BY date
  )                                AS month_to_date
FROM
  your_table
```

In the first case, it's just saying sum up the `value` column, in `date` order, starting from 4 rows before the current row, and ending on the current row.

In the second case, there's no `ROWS BETWEEN`, and so it defaults to all the rows preceding the current row up to the current row.  Instead, we add a `PARTITION BY` which says to treat all rows with the same calendar month separately from any rows on a different calendar month.  This, `all rows before the current one` only looks back to the first row in the partition, which is the first row in the current month.

---

In MySQL 5.x there are no such functions.  As such I would resort to correlated sub-queries.

```
SELECT
  *,
  (
    SELECT SUM(value)
      FROM your_table  AS five_day_lookup
     WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(your_table.date, INTERVAL 4 DAYS)
       AND date <=          your_table.date
  )
    AS five_day_period,
  (
    SELECT SUM(value)
      FROM your_table  AS monthly_lookup
     WHERE date >= DATE(DATE_FORMAT(your_table.date, '%Y-%m-01'))
       AND date <=                  your_table.date
  )
    AS month_to_date
FROM
  your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a other way to do that:

```
Select
      t1.`mydate` AS 'Date'
    , t1.`val` AS 'Value'
    
    , SUM( IF(t2.`mydate` >= t1.`mydate` - INTERVAL 4 DAY,t2.val,0)) AS '5 Day Period'
    , SUM( IF(t2.`mydate` >= DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(t1.`mydate` ),INTERVAL 1 DAY),INTERVAL - 1 MONTH),t2.val,0)) AS 'Month of Date'

FROM tab t1
LEFT JOIN tab t2 ON t2.`mydate`
    BETWEEN LEAST( DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(t1.`mydate` ),INTERVAL 1 DAY),INTERVAL - 1 MONTH),
            t1.`mydate` - INTERVAL 4 DAY)
    AND t1.`mydate`
GROUP BY t1.`mydate`
ORDER BY t1.`mydate` desc;
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [bkvie]> SELECT * FROM tab;
+----+------------+------+
| id | mydate     | val  |
+----+------------+------+
|  1 | 2021-02-07 |   10 |
|  2 | 2021-02-06 |   30 |
|  3 | 2021-02-05 |   40 |
|  4 | 2021-02-04 |   50 |
|  5 | 2021-02-03 |   10 |
|  6 | 2021-02-02 |   20 |
|  7 | 2021-01-31 |   20 |
|  8 | 2021-01-30 |   10 |
|  9 | 2021-01-29 |   30 |
| 10 | 2021-01-28 |   40 |
| 11 | 2021-01-27 |   20 |
| 12 | 2021-01-26 |   30 |
| 13 | 2021-01-25 |   10 |
| 14 | 2021-01-24 |   40 |
| 15 | 2021-02-01 |   10 |
+----+------------+------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**result**

```
MariaDB [bkvie]> Select
    ->  t1.`mydate` AS 'Date'
    ->  , t1.`val` AS 'Value'
    ->  , SUM( IF(t2.`mydate` >= t1.`mydate` - INTERVAL 4 DAY,t2.val,0)) AS '5 Day Period'
    ->  , SUM( IF(t2.`mydate` >= DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(t1.`mydate` ),INTERVAL 1 DAY),INTERVAL - 1 MONTH),t2.val,0)) AS 'Month of Date'
    -> FROM tab t1
    -> LEFT JOIN tab t2 ON t2.`mydate`
    ->  BETWEEN LEAST( DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(t1.`mydate` ),INTERVAL 1 DAY),INTERVAL - 1 MONTH),
    ->  t1.`mydate` - INTERVAL 4 DAY)
    ->  AND t1.`mydate`
    -> GROUP BY t1.`mydate`
    -> ORDER BY t1.`mydate` desc;
+------------+-------+--------------+---------------+
| Date       | Value | 5 Day Period | Month of Date |
+------------+-------+--------------+---------------+
| 2021-02-07 |    10 |          140 |           170 |
| 2021-02-06 |    30 |          150 |           160 |
| 2021-02-05 |    40 |          130 |           130 |
| 2021-02-04 |    50 |          110 |            90 |
| 2021-02-03 |    10 |           70 |            40 |
| 2021-02-02 |    20 |           90 |            30 |
| 2021-02-01 |    10 |          110 |            10 |
| 2021-01-31 |    20 |          120 |           200 |
| 2021-01-30 |    10 |          130 |           180 |
| 2021-01-29 |    30 |          130 |           170 |
| 2021-01-28 |    40 |          140 |           140 |
| 2021-01-27 |    20 |          100 |           100 |
| 2021-01-26 |    30 |           80 |            80 |
| 2021-01-25 |    10 |           50 |            50 |
| 2021-01-24 |    40 |           40 |            40 |
+------------+-------+--------------+---------------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)



MariaDB [bkvie]>
```

Comment: Strictly, you should add `val` to the GROUP BY or use MIN/MAX/ANY. Although legacy behavior does allow your syntax, I don't recommend teaching it to others in SO answers.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. If I needed in the future to convert this to PostgresSQL do you know how the code should be edited?